# Is it possible to move to the end of document with some hot-key?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've found this:

```
Ctrl+End     Move to the last cell with content on a worksheet.
```

But it moves me to  1156 line when document actually ends at 74.

Is there another possible way of doing it?

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing in line 1156? There could be a space or some other invisible character there.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 yes I'm sure.

Comment: @Heather Have you tried deleting all the rows from 1156 to 75?  If excel is going there, it is because it has something in the row somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open a new excel document and put some info on the first 5 rows, it only has 5 rows.
Remove the values from the last 2 rows and it still has 5 rows.
You have to right click on the number of the row 4 and 5 and click 'Delete' before the document has 3 rows.
You can test this by the hotkey you already found.

If you ever had data in row 1156, excel still remembers all rows until 1156 as a part of the data.

Comment: That's still being a bit weird, I need something to get into last place with some data.

Comment: You can do CTRL + END, you'll be at row 1156 now. Press CTRL + UP key, you'll be on row 74. That is as fast as you can get without removing the empty rows. It seems that in some cases, this will also remove the empty rows, but nothing is guaranteed there.

Answer (score 1):

Excel remembers deleted rows and still counts them as cells with values. A common solution is to save and reopen your workbook after you have deleted your rows. Reopening forces Excel to forgot those deleted rows and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> is working properly.

---

A way without saving and reopening is to use a simple VBA function. Once its set up, you can use it all the time by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd>. Its also possible to save it as an Excel-Addin and enable it for all Excel files.

1. Open your VBA editor in Excel with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>
2. On the left pane you see *ThisWorkbook*. Open it and paste this code.

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Application.OnKey "^{END}", "GoToLastCell"
   End Sub
   ```

   This will register your shortcut to our own function "GoToLastCell".
   If you wish to use another shortcut, choose one of the possibilities [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461%28v=office.15%29.aspx).
3. Insert a new **module** in the left pane, open it and paste this code.

   ```
   Function GoToLastCell()
       Set Lastrow = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=[A1], searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
       Lastrow.Select
   End Function
   ```

   It determines the last cell and selects it. Save your work and reopen the workbook to enable it.
   Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> to find the real last cell.

---

There is a difference between the find parameters `xlByRows` and `xlByColumns`. See the result.

```
             xlByRows                           xlByColumns
```

[image][image]